# Which one takes higher precendence between value and forClass in FacesConverter annotation when defining custom converter?

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I have the following as annotation for the custom converter

```
 @FacesConverter(value="capsConverter", forClass=String.class)
      public class CapsConverter implements Converter{
       @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        return value.toUpperCase(); 
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,Object value) {
        if(value!=null && value instanceof String){
            String s = (String)value;
            s = WordUtils.capitalize(s.toLowerCase());
            return s;
        }
        return null;
    }

     }
```

Issue is, the converter sometimes gets called even when I didnt explicitly call it in my page, does the forClass have anything to do with the interference for my inputTexts, should I be using value only and remove forClass=String.class ?

Any shed of light is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It are actually two distinct ways of registering a converter. Both are mutually exclusive. They have no influence on each other and you can omit one or the other.

The `forClass` attribute will register the converter in the JSF application to kick in during processing and rendering of every model value of the specified type. In other words, with `forClass=String.class`, the converter will be implicitly invoked for **every** `String` typed input and output, unless the associated input/output component has already an explicit converter declared.

Generally you use `forClass` only for custom/complex types, not for standard types such as `String`, `Long`, `BigDecimal`, etc for which JSF has already builtin implicit converters.

So you should indeed remove it and rely on converter ID only.

```
@FacesConverter("capsConverter")
```

```
<h:someComponent ... converter="capsConverter" />
```

---

An example of correct appliance of `forClass` would be the following converter between a `Person` entity and a `String` representing its ID

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Person.class)
```

on something like

```
<f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.person}" />
```

which converts an incoming request parameter representing an entity ID like below

```
/edit-person.xhtml?id=42
```

to a fullworthy entity property in bean (without needing any additional logic in bean)

```
private Person person;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot BalusC for clarifying the issue for me. Much appreciated.

Comment: If, however, no answer is acceptable, and you have already found an answer on your own, then you're obligated to post it yourself and mark it accepted. This way you contribute to a better searchable Stack Overflow. People of course want to see questions with accepted answers.

Comment: Thank you for alerting me there, I usually up voted most of the time thinking it was a way of accepting an answer, thank you once again BalusC